# Service Unavailable running Vue app to Azure App Service on Linux

Tags: azure, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a web app using Vue and Azure App Service on Linux. I have been able to run my project successfully locally, but when I go to build it on the server, It gives me a Service Unavailable.

I am using NUXT, and I have the port set to 3000 (but i'm thinking it needs to be process.env.PORT) but am unsure how to set it.

Here are my logs:

```
2017-12-28 23:51:19.987 INFO  - Container logs
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262030070Z   _____                               
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262060870Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262065270Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262068270Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262071070Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262073970Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262076670Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262079070Z 
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262081470Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262090570Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2017-12-28T23:47:30.262093270Z 
2017-12-28T23:47:30.873698188Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2017-12-28T23:47:31.585835033Z Generating app startup command
2017-12-28T23:47:31.598205110Z Found scripts.start in package.json
2017-12-28T23:47:31.622921465Z Running npm start
2017-12-28T23:47:34.613812035Z 
2017-12-28T23:47:34.613840336Z > rapchat@1.0.0 start /home/site/wwwroot
2017-12-28T23:47:34.613844036Z > PORT=3000 nuxt build
2017-12-28T23:47:34.613846336Z 
2017-12-28T23:47:46.961289422Z 2017-12-28T23:47:46.943Z nuxt:build Building...
2017-12-28T23:47:55.010373380Z 2017-12-28T23:47:55.009Z nuxt:build App root: /home/site/wwwroot
2017-12-28T23:47:55.011085084Z 2017-12-28T23:47:55.010Z nuxt:build Generating /home/site/wwwroot/.nuxt files...
2017-12-28T23:47:55.285571198Z 2017-12-28T23:47:55.285Z nuxt:build Generating files...
2017-12-28T23:47:55.389093245Z 2017-12-28T23:47:55.388Z nuxt:build Generating routes...
2017-12-28T23:47:55.709850548Z 2017-12-28T23:47:55.709Z nuxt:build Building files...
2017-12-28T23:50:43.739654992Z Hash: [1m6564d52127cc0bc02817[39m[22m
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765815664Z Version: webpack [1m3.10.0[39m[22m
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765838664Z Time: [1m165962[39m[22mms
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765842564Z                                          [1mAsset[39m[22m       [1mSize[39m[22m  [1mChunks[39m[22m  [1m[39m[22m           [1m[39m[22m       [1mChunk Names[39m[22m
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765851664Z [1m[33mpages/yearinreview/_id.72cca8c6b7deec929d1d.js[39m[22m     [1m[33m489 kB[39m[22m       [1m3[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m  [1m[33m[big][39m[22m  pages/yearinreview/_id
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765856064Z                           [1m[32mimg/poly.83d4067.png[39m[22m    6.59 kB        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765859664Z                        [1m[32mimg/text_me.e29d1a4.png[39m[22m    7.96 kB        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765871364Z                    [1m[32mimg/google_play.ded200b.png[39m[22m    25.2 kB        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765875264Z                      [1m[33mimg/footer_bg.a6a365d.png[39m[22m     [1m[33m738 kB[39m[22m        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m  [1m[33m[big][39m[22m  
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765879164Z                      [1m[32mimg/poly_gold.8915b42.png[39m[22m    3.24 kB        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765882364Z                     [1m[32mimg/wavelength.3e69288.svg[39m[22m    15.1 kB        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765885664Z        [1m[33mlayouts/default.2c425b8d20c7ccbabce7.js[39m[22m     [1m[33m607 kB[39m[22m       [1m0[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m  [1m[33m[big][39m[22m  layouts/default
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765889564Z            [1m[33mpages/beats.1be9d4d425bc4b070538.js[39m[22m     [1m[33m496 kB[39m[22m       [1m1[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m  [1m[33m[big][39m[22m  pages/beats
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765893364Z         [1m[33mpages/raps/_id.29b3e0119b309f2f6acb.js[39m[22m     [1m[33m522 kB[39m[22m       [1m2[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m  [1m[33m[big][39m[22m  pages/raps/_id
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765901764Z                      [1m[32mimg/app_store.4a95f44.png[39m[22m    20.2 kB        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765905364Z [1m[33mpages/rapnamegenerator.ff8cffdc140b77fa2ea4.js[39m[22m     [1m[33m490 kB[39m[22m       [1m4[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m  [1m[33m[big][39m[22m  pages/rapnamegenerator
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765909064Z          [1m[32mlayouts/blank.ebc2fbcfdb81050f1203.js[39m[22m    4.37 kB       [1m5[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         layouts/blank
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765912464Z            [1m[32mpages/index.85eac62b3a21dec8f25c.js[39m[22m    10.5 kB       [1m6[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         pages/index
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765915764Z            [1m[32mpages/terms.4a4ecf0382d8eab0cb90.js[39m[22m    4.66 kB       [1m7[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         pages/terms
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765918964Z          [1m[32mpages/privacy.6d5f6e75849ee8948d68.js[39m[22m    7.63 kB       [1m8[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         pages/privacy
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765975165Z           [1m[32mpages/_error.f68a2f2856029d9b54b5.js[39m[22m  607 bytes       [1m9[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         pages/_error
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765981065Z                    [1m[33mapp.2ca9f8bb42c491af2573.js[39m[22m     [1m[33m447 kB[39m[22m      [1m10[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m  [1m[33m[big][39m[22m  app
2017-12-28T23:50:43.765984965Z                 [1m[32mcommon.02a832a1ad8a72340207.js[39m[22m     138 kB      [1m11[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         common
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766833471Z               [1m[32mmanifest.6564d52127cc0bc02817.js[39m[22m    1.96 kB      [1m12[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         manifest
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766839371Z                                       [1m[32mLICENSES[39m[22m    2.31 kB        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766842671Z  + 16 hidden assets
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766845071Z 
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766847471Z [1m[33mWARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (300 kB).
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766850171Z This can impact web performance.
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766852671Z Assets: 
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766854971Z   img/footer_bg.a6a365d.png (738 kB)
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766857371Z   layouts/default.2c425b8d20c7ccbabce7.js (607 kB)
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766859771Z   pages/beats.1be9d4d425bc4b070538.js (496 kB)
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766862271Z   pages/raps/_id.29b3e0119b309f2f6acb.js (522 kB)
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766864671Z   pages/yearinreview/_id.72cca8c6b7deec929d1d.js (489 kB)
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766867071Z   pages/rapnamegenerator.ff8cffdc140b77fa2ea4.js (490 kB)
2017-12-28T23:50:43.766871071Z   app.2ca9f8bb42c491af2573.js (447 kB)[39m[22m

2017-12-28 23:51:19.988 ERROR - Container rapchat-website_2 for site rapchat-website did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.0562799 sec
2017-12-28 23:51:23.303 INFO  - Starting container for site
2017-12-28 23:51:23.304 INFO  - docker run -d -p 23493:8080 --name rapchat-website_4 -e WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=6.11 -e APPSETTING_WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=6.11 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=rapchat-website -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=fe0131188d0d8f5d73dcfe80d52622f03cc3e387d146b0ac5101928f37ee6535 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/node:6.11.5_1710252240
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

To host one Azure App Service I found (on Windows anyway) you need:

- A server.js file
- A correct npm `start` task in your packages.config.

**server.js**

An [older basic version](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/examples/custom-server/server.js) or the new 1.x [examples](https://github.com/nuxt-community/create-nuxt-app/tree/master/template/server) for different node servers you can use. You can see in these how they use `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000`, where `process.env.PORT` is an environment variable set by default in Azure.

Potentially you can add an app setting in the portal for your app called `PORT` to override the default environment variable if you ever had to, but I don't know if it'd work as I'm guessing Azure host off a port they know, trust and expose willingly.

**npm start task**

`node server.js`, or try remove the task entirely as Azure (at least on Windows) runs the same automatically.

**Automated deployments**
I also setup git deployment for my app so it auto-deploys when I push commits to my master branch. I needed a custom post deployment script to run the npm tasks. Here's [my gist instructions](https://gist.github.com/benmccallum/226ae1b428157b9d5998a5ba27eadf59) if it helps. Again, for Windows, but you can take a default post-deploy Linux script and add the necessary custom lines like I did.